# Ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java

На данный момент прохожу обучение по книге "Изучаем JAVA" Кэтти Сьерра и Берт Бейтс. Начал писать игру морской бой (пока в упрощенном варианте). Всё сделал по книге, но при компилировании выдаёт ошибку, помогите найти и исправить ошибку.

Ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at _006_KorabliDemo.SimpleDotCom.checkYourself(SimpleDotCom.java:17)
    at _006_KorabliMyDemo.SimpleDotComTestDrive.main(SimpleDotComTestDrive.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Код основного класса:

```
public class SimpleDotComTestDrive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int numOfGuesses = 0;
        GameHelper helper = new GameHelper();
        SimpleDotCom theDotCom = new SimpleDotCom();
        int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*5);
        int[] locations = {randomNum, randomNum+1, randomNum+3};
        theDotCom.setlocationCells(locations);
        boolean isAlive = true;

        while (isAlive == true)
        {
            String guess = helper.getUserInput("Введите число");
            String result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guess);
            numOfGuesses++;
            if (result.equals("Потопил"))
            {
                isAlive = false;
                System.out.println("Вам потребовалось" + numOfGuesses + "попыток(и)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если необходимо добавлю код двух оставшихся классов.

Подскажите, что неправильно реализовано в методе checkYourself?

```
public class SimpleDotCom
{
    int[] locationCells;
    int numOfHits = 0;

    public void setlocationCells (int[] locs)
    {
        locationCells = locs;
    }

    public String checkYourself(String stringGuess)
    {
        int guess = Integer.parseInt(stringGuess);
        String result = "Мимо";
        for (int cell : locationCells)
        {
            if (guess == cell)
            {
                result = "Попал";
                numOfHits++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (numOfHits == locationCells.length)
        {
            result = "Потопил";
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка не в основном классе, а в `SimpleDotCom.java`, строка 17, в методе `checkYourself` (смотрите текст ошибки). Пожалуйста добавьте этот код.

Comment: Проблема в том, что строка, которую вводят, не является целым числом - класс Integer не может распарсить ввод так, чтобы преобразовать его в целое число.

Answer (score 1):

Если в `stringGuess` — недопустимое интегральное число, то `Integer.parseInt` приводит к ошибке.

Можно просить пользователя до тех пор, пока он не введёт допустимое число:

```
String guess, result;
boolean isValid = false;
do {
  try {
    guess = helper.getUserInput("Введите число");
    result = theDotCom.checkYourself(guess);
    isValid = true;
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(guess + " не является допустимым числом.");
  }
} while(!isValid);
```